# Few font-awsome icons not getting displayed

Tags: html, css, angular, font-awesome

I am very new to web-designing. I am trying to use font awesome icons in the Angular 9 projects within a list item. All the icons I am trying to use are free and I have installed the same using pm. The problem which I am facing is that some of the icons are getting displayed properly but some aren't, Check the attached image. Using https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery&m=free to get the icons. Look at the attached image.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRZpc.png

HTML:

```
<div class="icons-list">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <div class="media-items">
                                <div class="media-left">
                                    <i class="fa fa-rocket fa-3x"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div class="media-body">
                                    <h4 class="title">56</h4><span class="title-description">Companies we helped</span></div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="media-items">
                                <div class="media-left">
                                    <i class="fas fa-briefcase fa-3x"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div class="media-body">
                                    <h4 class="title">12</h4><span class="title-description">Corporate Programs</span></div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="media-items">
                                <div class="media-left">
                                    <i class="fas fa-globe fa-3x"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div class="media-body">
                                    <h4 class="title">09</h4><span class="title-description">Services Provided across domains</span></div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="media-items">
                                <div class="media-left">
                                    <i class="fas fa-handshake fa-3x"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div class="media-body">
                                    <h4 class="title">32</h4><span class="title-description">Happy Clients</span></div>
                            </div>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <div class="media-items">
                                <div class="media-left">
                                    <i class="fa fa-user fa-3x"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div class="media-body">
                                    <h4 class="title">20</h4><span class="title-description">Awesome Employees</span></div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
```

Style.css

```
.media-body {
    display: table-cell;
}

.title {
    font-weight: 1000;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#736fb3, #55bce7);
    background-clip: border-box;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.title-description {
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

angular.json

```
"styles": [
                            "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
                            "./node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
                            "./src/styles.css"
                        ],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your css doesn't cover `fas`  change to `fa` and change `fa-handshake` to `fa-handshake-o`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<div class="icons-list">
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="media-items">
            <div class="media-left">
                <i class="fa fa-rocket fa-3x"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="media-body">
                <h4 class="title">56</h4><span class="title-description">Companies we helped</span>                 </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="media-items">
            <div class="media-left">
                <i class="fa fa-briefcase fa-3x"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="media-body">
                <h4 class="title">12</h4><span class="title-description">Corporate Programs</span>                 </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="media-items">
            <div class="media-left">
                <i class="fa fa-globe fa-3x"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="media-body">
                <h4 class="title">09</h4><span class="title-description">Services Provided across domains</span></div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="media-items">
            <div class="media-left">
                <i class="fa fa-handshake-o fa-3x"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="media-body">
                <h4 class="title">32</h4><span class="title-description">Happy Clients</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li>
        <div class="media-items">
            <div class="media-left">
                <i class="fa fa-user fa-3x"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="media-body">
                <h4 class="title">20</h4><span class="title-description">Awesome Employees</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. It is working now.  It would really be helpful if you can help me to understand what mistake I was making earlier, Was there something wrong in copying the "<i class="fab fa-accusoft"></i>" from font-awesome was wrong or do I need to make some additional imports which I missed in global Style.css or anything else?

Comment: You're welcome . U can check this https://cdnjs.com/libraries/font-awesome. here there is all one css. It should cover also fas , fab etc. You can try it. And you may  use ofiical font awesome in angular  https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome here also simple example with it https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fontawesome-sample